# Groovy and SOAPUI MissingMethodException

Tags: groovy, soapui

In my endeavours to integrate WireMock, Groovy and SOAPUI, I have stumbled upon this issue:

org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MissingMethodExceptionNoStack: No signature of method: ***********.PingRequest.main() is applicable for argument types: ([Ljava.lang.String;) values: [[]] Possible solutions: wait(), wait(long), any(), find(), wait(long, int), each(groovy.lang.Closure)

Being almost utterly new to Groovy, I have no idea where to start looking. Could one of you wonderful people be a guiding light and show me where the solution lies?

Thanks awfully,

Angus

Here's the code:

```
public static final int PORT = 8080
def baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/**************************'
@Rule
 WireMockRule wireMockRule = new WireMockRule(PORT)
 private final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger( "PingRequest" )

 @Test
void testPingRequest() {
    given:       
        def http = new HTTPBuilder(baseUrl)
        def headers = ['Accept': 'application/xml', 'Content-Type': 'application/xml']
        def requestBody = '{}'

        http.handler.failure = http.handler.success

        when:
            def response = http.post(contentType: ContentType.XML, headers: headers, body: requestBody)

        then:
            wireMock.verifyThat(new RequestPatternBuilder(RequestMethod.GET, urlPathEqualTo("********************************")))
            response
            !response.errors
}
```

}

Full stack trace sans package name (thanks for the heads up Michal M):

org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MissingMethodExceptionNoStack: No signature of method: ******.******.******.*****.*****.PingRequest.main() is applicable for argument types: ([Ljava.lang.String;) values: [[]] Possible solutions: wait(), wait(long), any(), find(), wait(long, int), each(groovy.lang.Closure)

Comment: could you share your code? do you use groovy as a test step?

Comment: Code added. Thanks

Comment: 1. Could you please add the full stack trace as well? 2. You may want to consider removing the package path from the PingRequest class in your questions, companies usually frown upon that in stackoverflow questions and it's easily googleable